# Correct way to share configuration between Gradle modules in multi-module project

Tags: java, gradle

I have a large multi-module Gradle project with 50 microservices and a few shared libraries. Both Scala and Java code is built out of the same gradle project.

Currently I have a setup like this (I've just listed the gradle files for simplicity):

```
/build-script/java-library.gradle
/build-script/java-project.gradle
/build-script/scala-library.gradle
/build-script/scala-project.gradle
/java-lib/build.gradle
/scala-lib/build.gradle
/java-proj/build.gradle
/scala-proj/build.gradle
/build.gradle
```

`/build.gradle` is empty

`/build-script/java-library.gradle` contains:

```
spotless { ... }
sourceSets { ... }
test { ... }
dependencies { ... }
```

Note I can't specify the plugins as its an include file.

`/build-script/java-project.gradle` contains:

```
apply from: "${project.rootDir}/build-script/java-library.gradle"

dependencies { ... }
```

Note I can't specify the plugins as its an include file.

In `/java-lib/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id "java-library"
  id "com.diffplug.spotlesss"
}

apply from: "${project.rootDir}/build-script/java-library.gradle"

dependencies { ... }
```

In `/java-proj/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id "java"
  id "com.diffplug.spotlesss"
}

apply from: "${project.rootDir}/build-script/java-project.gradle"

dependencies { ... }
```

Basically I'm using a load of *include* files, but I can't specify the plugin along with the configuration so feels a little "off".

What is the correct/cannonical way to share gradle configuration between modules in a multi-module gradle project?

Comment: Are you aware of Gradle [convention plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html)?